# Deploy config only upgrade package for azure service fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

When building an upgrade package for Configuration only (lets say MyConfig from the [canonical sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-application-model/#package-an-application)). Cannot find the details of what manifest files should include. Since there are two manifest files (`ApplicationManifest.xml` and `ServiceManifest.xml`) what should go into the config only upgrade package? A pointer to a sample would be great.

Comment: I've created a blog post with detailed steps: https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/updating-azure-service-fabric-settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd provide the same layout structure as the full package but you'd remove everything that's not relevant to what you're updating.  So, using the example you linked to, you'd only include these files:

- ApplicationManifest.xml
- MyServiceManifest\ServiceManifest.xml
- MyServiceManifest\MyConfig\Settings.xml

Comment: Thank you Matt. Important information to note is that even if the config is changing, both, application and service have to get a new version (and not just the config section). While the documentation shows a sample (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-application-upgrade-tutorial-powershell/) the concept is a bit buried under the specific sample details.